# session attributes with integer, cannot be resolved to type

Tags: java, jsp

im having a problem with my jsp, i have just added a new column to my ms access table called member No, but i am having problems using it in the session.

```
session.setAttribute("memberNo", new integer (results.getInt("memberNo")));
```

in the main class i have

```
integer memberNo = (integer)session.getAttribute("memberNo");
```

im getting an errors saying integer cannot be resolved to type

thanks

Comment: It should be upper case i: Integer not integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `integer` should be either `int` or `Integer` there is no such type as integer in Java.

Java naming convention expects that all types start with capital letter.

Comment: It can't be a primitive int, `setAttribute` and `getAttribute` work on `Object`s only.

Comment: @Funtik You can make use of autoboxing to setAttribute, but will not work when getting: `int memberNo = (int) session.getAttribute("memberNo");` is not compiling

Answer (score 1):

Its not `integer,` You need to use [`Integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html)